# docker is stopped, still webpage is rendered in browser

Tags: docker

I had run container on my local.

When I type "localhost:80" in my browser, it opens the website page which I had loaded through container.( i have attached content of localhost below ).

Issue : **Not able to stop the running container.**

Tried commands : 
-> `docker container ls`  ----prints nothing, just header of the tables

-> `docker container ls -a` ---- prints container that I had loaded.

-> `docker ps` ---- prints nothing, just header of the tables

-> `docker ps -a` ---- prints container that I had loaded.

-> `docker stop dockerName` ---- > in my case docker name is , "my-first-ginx"

-> `docker stop dockerId` ----> in my case docker id is , 05de0a976988

-> `docker kill dockerId` --- > Got an Error message, described as below ,

**Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 05de0a976988: Container 05de0a976988d1c323981bcbc342dfc9cec79a08162e6ec4de184dad5289cfc5 is not running**

First Screenshot is proof that there exists container named "my-first-nginx"

Third Screenshot is proof that it's still running when I hit on localhost:80

Second screenshot is proof that I can't kill that container, because it's not running.

I have started learning docker today only, so pls someone help, what mistake I am making ?

[image]

[image]
[image]

UPDATE :

After removing all the stopped containers , still I am getting the website page on "localhost:80" .

[image]

Comment: The application is not running but it is still present as a container: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` to remove all stopped container

Comment: hmm, I also understand the fact that application is not running. but why does it show the website home page, when I type "localhost:80" on browser,,, that's the most confusing part for me :( . I am stuck here from last 3 hours :( .

Comment: After `killall -HUP dockerd` still shows landing page?

Comment: @MatteoRagni, pls check update in the question part.

Comment: can you try a sighup to the docker daemon? `killall -HUP dockerd`

Comment: @MatteoRagni , This is the error I found "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170308/discussion-between-matteo-ragni-and-neer-patel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the browser is caching the welcome page. 
It is a simple GET, and hence the browser caches it instead of doing a actual call to get the contents of the url it is just loading the page from cache.

To validate this do a `Ctrl+F5` on Windows or `Option+Shift+R` on OSX and that would indicate to the browser to go fetch the latest and ignore the cache.

And then you can see that it fails as the docker container is not running.

Comment: it worked ! . it was unwanted caching done by chrome.